# Using jQuery to bind ajax data

Tags: c#, jquery

I am getting data back from my C# WebMethod. I'm not sure how to bind the Key and Value from my WebMethod to my dropdown:

```
 <select name="rest" id="rest" maxlength="50" style="width: 200px;"></select>
```

**C#**

```
 [WebMethod]
public static Dictionary<string, string> LoadRestByCityState(string city, string state)
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(ConfigManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString.Data"]);
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_RestByCityState_p");
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@pListCity", DbType.String, city);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@pListState", DbType.String, state);
        ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);

        Dictionary<string, string> rest = new Dictionary<string,string>();

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            rest.Add(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString());
        }
            return rest;

}
```

**jQuery**

```
  function LoadRest() {
        __state = $("#State :selected").val();
        __state = '"' + __state + '"'
        __city = $("#City :selected").val();
        __city = '"' + __city + '"'
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/LoadRestByCityState",
            data: '{"city":' + __city + ',"state":'+ __state +'}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success:
                function (data) {
                    $.each(data[0], function(key....not sure about this stuff
                    alert('parks loaded');
                },
            fail: function () {
                alert("Error.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

**Data**
This is being passed to WebMethod

```
{
"state": "AL",
"city": "Auburn"
}
```

When debugging my WebMethod, I hover over 'rest' and it shows the Key and Value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a dictionary as this doesn't serialize as a collection. Use a list:

```
public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> LoadRestByCityState(string city, string state)
{
    ...
}
```

And then:

```
success: function (data) {
    var rest = $('#rest');
    rest.empty();
    $.each(data.d, function(index, item) {
        rest.append(
            $('<option/>', {
                value: item.Key,
                text: item.Value
            })
        );
    });
}
```

also make sure to properly encode your values before sending them. I would recommend you using the JSON.stringify method because if the city has a quote in its name your request will break:

```
data: JSON.stringify({city: __city, state: __state }),
```

The [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) method is built into modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
success : function(data){
   $.each(data, function(index, elem){
      $.each(elem, function(key,value){
         $('select#rest').append('<option value="'+key+'">"'+value+'"</option>');  
      });
   });
}
```

**update:** other  solution

```
success : function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, elem){
          for(var key in elem){
             $('select#rest').append('<option value="'+key+'">"'+elem[key]+'"</option>');  
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: Im getting 0 and ["object Object"] in my dropdown. Still returning the correct JSON values though.